# select the union of several tables together in a single step

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I am very new to Oracle 11g and am trying to generate a large string by appending text for each column in a select statement and using a cursor to store the results.  However I want the last statement to not have a union all included.  The final result I want to build large string of each row generated or simply execute the result if possible.

Note: column1 has a list of schemas that I am interested in.

```
select 'select * from ' || column1 || '.' || column2 || ' union all ' from mytable
```

This is where column1 is the schema, column2 is the table name.

What is the simplest way to generate the final string without using rtrim to remove the last string.  And is there a simple way to append all these rows together in the string automatically?

The final goal is to actually just execute the union into a resulting cursor.

Comment: How are you bulding up the string - appending the result inside a cursor loop? And how long might the final string be? Bigger than the varchar2 size limit?

Comment: I'm building a varchar2 for test purposes.  It is much smaller than 32k.

Answer (score 1):

If you're querying in a loop anyway I wouldn't try to construct the string as part of the select at all; I'd do it all within the loop. Something like (untested):

```
declare
  str varchar2(32768);
begin
  for rec in (select column1, column2, rownum as rn from mytable)
  loop
    if rec.rn > 1 then
      str := str || ' union all ';
    end if;
    str := str || 'select * from "' || rec.column[ || '"."' || rec.column2 ||'"';
  end loop;

  -- do something with str e.g. display to verify the syntax
  -- before using in a cursor
  dbms_output.put_line(str);
end;
```

Rather than adding `union all` to the end of every row except the last one,the `rn` check means it's added to the *start* of every row except the first one, which is easier to detect.

I've also wrapped the schema and table names in double quotes, just in case you have to deal with any quoted identifiers. But if your stored values don't match the case of the owners and table names in `all_tables` this will cause a problem rather than solve it.